# writing a data stored in an array to multiple excel sheets using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I have two associative arrays which i have to write on two different sheets in one excel file.

This is what i tried for single sheet with one array

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
$excel_name=$_POST['excel_name'];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$excel_name.'.xls"');
print_r($_POST['html_excel']); 
?>
```

where 'html_excel' is my associative array

Now i want to know how to create multiple excel sheets without using PHPExcel or any other library and print my associative arrays into it.

Please help...
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly,But i don't want to use any library.I want it to be done the same way what i have done for single excel sheet

Comment: So how are you going to tell it the sheet name. Thats the point of sugesting a library

Comment: Is it possible to create multiple workbooks inside one excel sheet in the way that i have done to create a excel sheet above?

Comment: As you have no way to tell excel the sheet to use I can see no obvious way. Although I must admit I have not ever done it your way.